# Why are HTML Input element ID attribute values being prefixed in a form I am emailing?

Tags: php, html, forms, html-email

I am using PHP to compose a HTML form to be sent by email. I have, for example, code like this:

```
$userOutput .= '<input type="hidden" id="seenUser" name="seenUser" value="'.$lastUsername.'">';
$userOutput .= '<input type="hidden" id="seenToken" name="seenToken" value="'.$userToken.'">';
```

When that email arrives in my inbox, if I use Firefox's code inspector, it shows the elements as:

```
<input type="hidden" id="x_683480324seenUser" name="seenUser" value="someUsername">
<input type="hidden" id="x_683480324seenToken" name="seenToken" value="6ed3738a6e20f56f83ec83d9ef77a169">
```

Why do the id attribute values have prefixes `x_683480324`?

On the page intended to receive the form submission, I am using:

```
if (isset($_POST['seenUser'])&&isset($_POST['seenToken'])) {
```

... and this is obviously failing on account of the unpredictable prefix.

**Long Version**

Here is the form as it appears in my web mail. Clearly the `onSubmit` has been added by my web mail provider. It seems reasonable to conclude the changes to the `form` `id` value, as well as those in my question - `input` `id` values - were probably also modified by the web mail provider.

```
<form id="x_-381141859birdsSeen" action="https://www.MYDOMAIN.com.au/MYPAGE.php" method="post" onsubmit="return window.confirm(&quot;You are about to send information to an external page. Do you want to continue?&quot;);" target="_blank">
    <h4>Pacific Baza <input type="checkbox" name="pacbaz1" value="pacbaz1"></h4>
    2019-10-23 - <a href="https://www.OBFUSCATED.org/" target="_blank">AU-NSW-KRG</a>
    <br>
    <h4>Whiskered Tern <input type="checkbox" name="whiter2" value="whiter2"></h4>
    2019-10-22 - <a href="https://www.OBFUSCATED.org/" target="_blank">AU-NSW-NEW</a>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" id="x_-381141859seenUser" name="seenUser" value="OBFUSCATED">
    <input type="hidden" id="x_-381141859seenToken" name="seenToken" value="8c1865d190e5a11d2cfe548224bf8d56">
    <input type="submit" value="Seen them!">
</form>
```

Before getting a lecture, I understand that it may be the case not all mail providers will support the use of a form in email. Be that as it may, this form *does* work when I modify my checking of the $_POST parameters (compared with the code given in the question above) per below:

```
foreach($_POST as $postName=>$postValue) {

    echo 'PostVar: '.$postName.'<br />';

    if (substr($postName, -8)==='seenUser'&&strlen($postName)>8) { // The POST variable name is longer than 8 chars and the last 8 chars are 'seenUser'
        $postedSeenUser = $postValue; // assign the convoluted variable's value to our nice simple name
    }

    if (substr($postName, -9)==='seenToken'&&strlen($postName)>9) { // The POST variable name is longer than 9 chars and the last 9 chars are 'seenToken'
        $postedSeenToken = $postValue; // assign the convoluted variable's value to our nice simple name
    }

    if ($postName==='seenUser') $postedSeenUser = $postValue;   // Just in case the variable arrives with nice clean name as desired
    if ($postName==='seenToken') $postedSeenToken = $postValue; // Just in case the variable arrives with nice clean name as desired

} // And now our variables should contain nice neat seenUser and seenToken values if they existed in some convoluted manner.

if (isset($postedSeenUser)&&isset($postedSeenToken)) {
```

While it may be the case it is those last two "catch the simple case" statements that lead the above to work, the question remains as to why the following should not have worked in the first place:

```
if (isset($_POST['seenUser'])&&isset($_POST['seenToken'])) {
```

Comment: Do you have any other instances of `<input ... id="seenUser"...` in the document? If you're duplicating code, there's a change this is auto-prefixing to prevent duplicate id's. It's a bit hard to know without knowing more about your code generation, your email client and the framework you're using.

Comment: It's hand-coded (ie. no framework). It looks through a MySQL result set array and builds a copy of this form, in a string, for each result. The string, containing the entire form, is put into an array. Later, the code iterates through that array and for each element, prepares and sends an email. In effect, while processing the PHP, multiple input elements may exist - but only as string content - having ID "seenUser". However within each email generated, that ID should exist only once. The email client is Zoho web mail.

Comment: _“... and this is obviously failing on account of the unpredictable prefix.”_ - what would the _IDs_ have to do with that? The form submission parameter names are based on the _names_ of the input fields, not the IDs, and according to what you have shown us, these names appear unchanged.

Comment: @04FS I hope the down vote wasn't from you on that account? Regardless of the last statement, the question still stands: why are the ID values being modified? To speak to your comment though, after iterating through the posted parameters via `foreach($_POST as $postName=>$postValue)`, checking for any with `$postName` ending in `seenUser` or `seenToken` and explicitly being longer than 8 and 9 characters respectively, the code entered my conditional statement yet when coded as given in my question, it wouldn't.  Regardless of documentation to the contrary, this is what I observed.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do the id attribute values have prefixes `x_683480324`?

By looking at the full code for the `form` element, it became clear there were other additions to the form. One, in particular (the `onSubmit` property) suggested it was the web mail client that made that particular change, and therefore, probably the others also.

> and this is obviously failing on account of the unpredictable prefix.

One commentator pointed out that the code cannot have been failing on account of the `id` properties because `isset` operates on the `name` properties, which remained unmodified.

There was no resolution as to why the code failed at this point. A workaround which handles both cases - `isset` processing `name` values and/or `id` values - works, per the example in the question.